# How to change the return type of memoizer?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the return type of memoizer to `Future<List<MyModel>>` However, I can't seem to find a way to change it.  It always return as `Future<dynamic>`

Here's my code:

```
  final AsyncMemoizer _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer();

  Future<List<MyModel>> getSometing() async {
    return this._memoizer.runOnce(() async {
      return await getData();
    });
    
  }
```

Comment: Did you try passing a type to the constructor?  Looks like it's a generic: AsyncMemoizer<T>

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, but I did play around including typecast the return type and it's still not working.

Comment: `final _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer<List<MyModel>>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final AsyncMemoizer<List<MyModel>> _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer<List<MyModel>>();

Future<List<MyModel>> getSometing() async {
  return this._memoizer.runOnce(() async {
    return await getData();
  });
}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.